# Cannot import ArcPy from ArcGIS Pro 2.5.2 in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, arcgis, arcpy

I have ArcGIS Pro 2.5.2 installed, and have created a new virtual environment in PyCharm using the interpreter located here:

```
C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\python.exe
```

I have copied the ArcGISPro.pth file into my virtual environment so that it knows where ArcPy is located. When I run a script that simply says:

```
import arcpy
```

I get the following, slightly hard to follow error:

```
C:\Users\lharris\PycharmProjects\arcpro_test\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/lharris/PycharmProjects/arcpro_test/test.py
arcpy must be run from inside the Conda environment, which ArcGIS
Traceback (most recent call last):
uses to manage the installation of Python.
  File "C:/Users/lharris/PycharmProjects/arcpro_test/test.py", line 1, in <module>
You can access this environment by launching Python from the links inside the
    import arcpy
"ArcGIS > ArcGIS Pro" Start Menu Group:
    "Python Interactive Terminal" starts a Python session.
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\__init__.py", line 70, in <module>
    "Python Command Prompt" opens a Command Prompt window initialized with Conda.

Or by running the proenv.bat file in the terminal:
    raise ImportError("arcpy needs to run within an active ArcGIS Conda environment")
     C:\> C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\python\scripts\proenv.bat

ImportError: arcpy needs to run within an active ArcGIS Conda environment

Process finished with exit code 1
```

When I open a terminal with that Python interpreter, it says:

```
Warning:
This Python interpreter is in a conda environment, but the environment has
not been activated. Libraries may fail to load.  To activate this environment
please see https://conda.io/activation
```

I believe that ArcGIS Pro has been updated (this is on a server at work, so I don't really have control of that). However I previously had no problem importing ArcPy. So, could this be a new problem specific to this updated version? Is it something to do with Arc's use of Conda?

**How do I use the version of Python that comes bundled with ArcGIS Pro 2.5.2 with PyCharm?**

Answer (score 1):

According to the [link](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/guide/install-and-set-up/) the environment name is `arcgispro-py3`

Therefore, I assume your environment name is `arcgispro-py3`

1- Open your terminal or command prompt and type: `conda activate arcgispro-py3`. If this statement is successfully executed. You will see a screen like this:

[image]

If you have an error after execution, that means your environment name is different. You need to replace your environment name with the `arcgispro-py3`.

2- Now type `python`

3- and type `import arcpy` enter:

If you have an error on the step-3, then exit the python by `exit()` and install the environment: `conda install -c esri arcpy`

4- type `import arcpy` again

Now I assume this will sove your problem, otherwise you may need to reinstall ArcGIS again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can't do this because I don't use conda, it's not installed on the machine in question so I get a `'conda' is not recognized as an internal or external command` error. I use PyCharm as my IDE, as well as it's built in pip-based package manager. My question is how do I import arcpy in a virtual environment created by PyCharm - something that until recently I could do no problem.